# The camera pluggin for flutter is not working like it is supposed and keeps giving a large error message

Tags: flutter

This is my code

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "dart:io";
import "package:image_picker/image_picker.dart";

class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
 u/override
 _ImageInputState createState() => _ImageInputState();
}

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
 u/override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 File _storedImage;

 _takePicture() async {
 PickedFile imageFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
 setState(() {
        _storedImage = File(imageFile.path);
      });
 print(_storedImage == null);
    }

 return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
 Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration:
 BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
          child: _storedImage != null
              ? DecorationImage(
                  image: FileImage(_storedImage),
                )
              : Text("No Image Taken", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
        ),
 SizedBox(
          width: 10,
        ),
 Expanded(
          child: FlatButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
            label: Text("Take Picture"),
            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            onPressed: _takePicture,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And whenever I click the camera Icon, the ide displays this error message

[Camera] Failed to read exposureBiasesByMode dictionary: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 "*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _initForReadingFromData:error:throwLegacyExceptions:]: data is NULL}

Can someone tell me why this is happening and offer a solution?

Comment: I got no error using your widget in a new Flutter app. Can you try creating a new app and place the code inside to see if the error still happens? Btw you should use real device when testing these features for less issues

Comment: I did create a new app and tested the same widget and I get the same error code. I also am using a real device. It still is not working. Is this just an issue with my phone? I think the issue is that the widget is not reloading.

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?